# Java: Iterator, Iterable - Interface or Abstract Class?

Tags: java

My question is quite simple, and it all started after I accidently saw the source code of the Iterable interface. I thought I will find this interface has a member of an abstract-class called "AbstractIterator" or something like that, but it turns out it's an interface.

Why? Why isn't Iterator an Abstract class? 
Interfaces are used to define a certain trait - that's why the 'able' ending pops out on so many of them. But it turns out that java holds a different view, as it seems. Explanation, please...:)

P.s: List, Set etc are also, in my view, supposed to be abstract classes - so my question is about 'em as well...

Comment: why the should be abstract classes? if what you want is to impose a contract, then an interface is enought (`java.util.List`), if you want to impose a contract and share behaviour then you could to with an abstract class (`java.util.AbstractList`)

Comment: As for as set, list and the other Collections stuff goes, they may have similar use (thus an interface) but their implementations are very different, just consider an arraylist and linkedlist, if they were subclassed from an abstract list they would have to rewrite alot of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each implementation of `Iterator` is unique to the collection it is iterating. These is not enough common code to warrant an abstract base class.

That said the use of an interface is much less restrictive than an abstract class. Remember that in Java a class may only extend a single base class. So if these interfaces were abstract classes implementors would not be able to extend any other class. Using an interface leaves gives the implementor complete class hierarchy freedom.

It is very common to have an interface and an abstract class. This combination allows for complete freedom to implement the interface but allows for code reuse in the cases where implementations can use the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Java allows multiple inheritance for interfaces only, classes (including abstract classes) can only utilize single inheritance. So when you would make a `List` an abstract class you would force any implementor to follow your class design, no matter what his functional and business requirements would demand. Plus you couldn't implement different behaviour in one class. Something that e.g. implements a `Stack` behaviour plus a `List` behaviour would not be possible.

As partial implementations are often useful you will sometimes find a triptychon of interface, abstract class and default implementation in the JDK, e.g. with `TableModel`, `AbstractTableModel` and `DefaultTableModel`. You can choose how much you want to be bound to the class hierarchy. When you already have a hierarchy that forces you to use a specific class you still can implement the interface.

Java is quite static in this regard. One should favour composition over inheritance here more than in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of declaring Iterator as Interface is to give clients a simple way to walk through each item of your internal collection without to give him information about the concrete implementation (i.e. ArrayList, Vector, XML-File?, ...).

So the Iterator Design Pattern makes the concrete implementation interchangable without changing the clients code.

Furthermore, you are able to write your own implementations of the iterator without any limitations, that is the most important advantage of declaring the Iterator as Interface. You could for example write an Iterator, to iterate over a specific database Table, or to iterate over the lines of a text.

Google for the "Iterator Design Pattern" to get some more information about its advantages (and disadvantages) and its usage.

Regards,
Bob